# Laravel Socialite with Google saves different ID number, causes duplicate error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I got Laravel 5.2 and the latest version of Socialite to work properly with Twitter and Facebook login, but not with Google Login.

With Google, the user can log in the first time and get inserted into the database. However, when the user re-atttempts to log in after a log out, there is a problem. In my callback function, the getId() call is returning a number such as 1048710206853583#####. However, in the MySQL database, a number such as 92233720368547##### is getting stored after the user's first login in a provider_id field. This is happening with one single getId() call that I'm using. It appears that Google is returning two different Ids. Could this be? What could I be doing wrong?

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider = null)
{
    if(!config("services.$provider")) abort('404'); //handle providers that don't exist

    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider = null)
{
    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    $oauth_id = $social_user->getId();

    $user = User::where('oauth_id', $oauth_id)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $social_user->getEmail();
        if($social_user->getNickname() && strlen( $social_user->getNickname() ) > 0)
            $user->username = $social_user->getNickname();
        else
            $user->username = $social_user->getEmail();
        $user->oauth_id = $oauth_id;
        $user->oauth_type = $provider;
        $user->password = null;
        $user->confirmation_code = null;
        $user->save();

    }

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its funny but for me it was a silly mistake that cost me valuable time.

my database column was set to `varchar(20)`

The google `getID()` is `21 in length` i.e requires `varchar(21)`

so the last number is always truncated. That's why the value returned by my query is always false.

i had to set my database column to `varchar(25)` just in case and all is fine now.

Happy coding...